# Why doesn't the debugger hit this breakpoint consistently? Am I neglecting a file handle?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, idisposable, breakpoints, embedded-resource

Consider the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Resources.SampleXMLFile)) // Breakpoint set here
    {
        using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(memoryStream))
        {
            var z = XElement.Load(xmlTextReader);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have a breakpoint set on the first using statement. Yet, the debugger does not hit it consistently.

My question:

> Why does this happen? Am I neglecting a file handle?

Also:

> Is this the best way to open an embedded resource XML file?

Comment: Are you using a remote debugger and is this just a sample block of code? If you are using a remote debugger and the file that is compiled on the remote host is different from your local file it can cause the issue where your break points are not hit.

Comment: @Dan: Good question. However, I'm not using a remote debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who viewed this question.

Here is how I fixed this problem:

> Closed and reopened Visual Studio.

As an aside, I had a total of three Visual Studio instances open at the time.

Shame on me for failing to consider that my machine might have had insufficient resources to execute the code.